# S3 upload feasibility

Tags: amazon-s3

I've already asked this question on the AWS forums but haven't had a response yet so I thought I'd up it up a bit to see if anyone here might have an idea about this:

We've a client who's talking about doing a project next year which would see up to 10 million people upload up to 5x 4MB files over a 24 hours period.

I guess I'd like to know if this seems way too much for s3 to be able to cope with, or maybe it'd be so insignificant it wouldn't cause any issues.

If we take these numbers as the max possible then a quick rough estimate would give

10 million X 5 X 4 = 200,000,000MB = 200TB

We'd be looking at an average transfer rate over 24 hours of around

8TB per hour
140GB per minute
2.3 GB per second

This obviously doesn't account for peaks in usage.

So, is this a 'Christ that's insane' or a 'Yeah should be fine' or somewhere inbetween?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is a question anyone outside of Amazon's own datacenter can really answer.  Have you tried contacting [amazon tech support](http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/) directly?

Comment: It doesn't look like they have free tech support, or am I missing it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a 1x 24 hour event/spike or are your figures per-24 hours on a rolling basis? If the latter, I would go back and question your figures as that sounds like extremely high volume of upload traffic over a sustained period.

If we're talking 1x 24 hour event then we're talking 200TB in total. Simplistically that's like 200 1TB hard drives (not accounting for RAID configuration etc). I'm sure Amazon S3 can easily handle that.

As for the upload/transfer rate, Amazon S3 is massively distributed, so it's not like you're trying to achieve 2.3Gb per sec to a single machine over a single link.

Comment: Yes it'd only be a one off 24 hour period. I'm glad you don't think it's completely insane. In reality they probably won't get anywhere near those numbers of people involved, but we have to at least be prepared for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a response from an Amazonian on their forums:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=77419&tstart=0

> Hello,
>
> S3 was designed from the ground up to handle traffic for any Internet
>   application. I don't see why your use case can cause any problems.

So it sounds like we should be ok. Fingers crossed!